# Replace empty space '' to NULL or keep it when saving data to database table depending the data type

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to read a csv file and save it into a table in Snowflake (a database).

The problem is that the empty space in the file has to be converted to `NULL` or **not changed** depending on the data type and/or nullability of the column in the table.

An example file of table_a.csv is below:
it is an empty space for ColA,ColB and ColC in row 2.

```
Id, ColA,  ColB, ColC

1,hello,2,'2020-1-1'

2,,,
```

Expected data in the table below after importing table_a.csv below:

**Table table_a in the database**

```
Id, ColA,  ColB, ColC

1    hello  2   2020-1-1

2    ''     NULL  NULL
```

On row 2,

ColA: an empty space ''

ColB: a NULL

ColC: a NULL

**Schema of table table_a**

```
Id int primary key,
ColA varchar not null,
ColB int null,
ColC date time null
```

Please note that ColA is non-nullable, but ColB and ColC is nullable.

Below below

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('table_a.csv')
Tried: 
1 replace empty space with NA - this doesn't work for ColA
2 not replace empty space with NA - this doesn't work for ColB etc.
write_pandas(df, 'table_a')
```

The solution must be generic and cannot specify any column name, as there are 30 tables, and many columns in each table.

**Summary**

Is it possible for pandas to handle this issue, i.e. keep an empty string '' in one column in a CSV file for one column in the table, while converting an empty string in another column in the csv to `na/null` for another column in the same table?

Comment: Two things: 1) is it possible to change the csv so that you use optional quote qualifiers on columns where you want to store blanks, rather than NULL? 2) if not on #1, are you able to modify the tables to have NOT NULL on those columns with a default of blank?  That would force the insert to write a blank instead of a NULL.

Comment: cannot change either csv or the table. Is it possible for pandas to handle this issue, i.e. keep an empty string '' in one column in a csv file for one column in the table, while converting an empty string in another column in the csv to na/null for another column in the same table?